# Is there a way to make page layout fit perfectly at 100% zoom but also respect greater zoom factors?

Tags: javascript, css, layout, zooming

There are several ways to layout web pages so they fit the browser viewport (DOM `window`). When I say "fit" I include changing the size of the fonts used and changing the width and perhaps heights of DIVs, IMGs, and other rendered elements, as well as allowing "fluid" movements of elements. The goal is to make the page look "nice" on all display devices, from tiny phones to big desktop screens. These layout ways include using CSS `em` and `%` sizes, wrapping of text and elements, and JavaScript run by the `onload` and `onresize` events. Layout fitting can be made to work almost perfectly, cross-browser, but a sophisticated result may be insensitive to browser zooming, since zooming changes the window width magically, which means without any browser-independent, reliable way to detect the zoom (DOM and CSS standards ignore browser zooming). There is no way to detect the difference between a small window width due to a small device screen versus a small window width due to a large zoom factor. We want to handle these two cases differently, since vision-impaired users need the zoom factor to be honored.

Has anyone succeeded in fitting layout really well (including changing font sizes) in a way that respects zooming? For example, if the user visits the page with a zoom of 200%, initially only the upper left quarter of the page should be shown (the rest being available by scrolling horizontally and vertically), while the same page would fit into the window perfectly for another user having their zoom set to 100%.

Comment: Expand and shrink your browser on [this site](http://oneapi.ru/showcases/) that I wrote. I can write an answer, in case anyone is interested in knowing how this was done.

Comment: Just visited your site. It doesn't respond to increasing the zoom at all. The question here has nothing to do with expanding or shrinking the browser window.

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos `500 Internal Server Error`, which indeed scales pretty well.

Comment: @SQB Unfortunately that site is now down. But [here](https://codepen.io/ruisoftware/pen/rjNMZJ) you can see how the button and the car respond to the browser width.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed to have a fluid layout you will have to use % to determine the width instead of pixels.
And for fitting the screen use 100%

Comment: This is not a good answer because it addresses only the question of fluid layout, and ignores browser zooming. The question is actually a very advanced, very difficult one, not just a beginner's question.

Answer (score -1):

Just add the following metatag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
                      initial-scale=1.0,
                      maximum-scale=1.0,
                      user-scalable=0">
```