# Scale text in navigation bar

Tags: css, responsive-design

In [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933943/is-there-a-way-to-make-page-layout-fit-perfectly-at-100-zoom-but-also-respect-g), a user(JoseRui Santos) gave a comment with an [intesting link.](http://oneapi.ru/showcases/)
How did the user  make the text scale in this example? I am particularly interested in the nav.

I have a wide nav that runs off the screen on a smaller screen.

I only have 45 points, so I can't ask him myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer used `vw` as the unit for font-size. This is responsive to the width of the viewport. See [this article](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) for a full explanation.

The relevant code in the example you linked is this:

```
body {
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    [...]
}
```

And then the font sizes in the nav are based off of that initial font size, using either `em` or `%` units, which are relative to the `body` font-size, so they also grow and shrink as the width of the viewport grows and shrinks.